# Auto delete files in subfolders after a certain count value

Tags: windows, batch-file

Can anyone please explain to me how batch scripts work in Windows? I have a folder that contains subfolders, and those contain images. I need a script that automatically deletes images from 7 and up in these subfolders, just to leave a maximum of 6 images in each subfolder, ideally the first 6 alphabetically. I found a few scripts, saved them as .bat, but I have no idea what to do next.

1

```
@echo off
setlocal
set /a cnt=0
set "keep=6"
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /o-d /a-d *.jpeg') do (
  if defined keep (
    2>nul set /a "cnt+=1, 1/(keep-cnt)" || set "keep="
  ) else del "%%F"
)
```

2

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('dir /b /o-d *.jpeg ^| findstr /N "^"') do (
   if %%a gtr 6 del "%%b"
)
```

3

```
for /f "skip=7 eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /o-d /a-d *.jpeg') do @del "%%F"
```

4

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

rem How many elements to keep
set "keep=6"

rem Retrieve folder from batch arguments
set "folder=%~1"

rem If no folder indicated, use current active directory
if not defined folder for %%a in (.) do set "folder=%%~fa"

rem Ensure we are working in the correct folder
pushd "%folder%" && (
    rem For each element in the folder, skipping the first n 
    for /f "skip=%keep% delims=" %%a in (' dir /b /on ') do (
        rem If it is a folder, use rmdir, else use del
        if exist "%%a\" ( echo rmdir /s /q "%%a" ) else ( echo del "%%a" )
    )
    rem Work done. Return to previous active directory
    popd
) || ( 
    rem Folder change failed
    echo Target folder does no exist 
)
```

Comment: are you asking how to execute a batch script? (btw: be sure to have a backup when you are not completely confident you really understand the code you "found on the internet")

Comment: Yes, because when I double-click on those bat files, they can be placed in that folder but nothing happens, the subfolders still have 7 or more files.

Comment: Open a command prompt, navigate to the folder where your batch file is stored and run it by typing it's name. When you remove `@echo off`, it shows you each line as it is executed. And most important: the window doesn't close when there is a syntax error. So you can read any errormessages. Without trying - each of the codes look valid to me at a first glance (note the last one just `echo`es the `rd` and `del` commands for safety)

Comment: Are you perfectly sure your file extensions are, as per the first 3 script examples, `.jpeg`? also, if you planned on delete from the subfolders, these scripts will not work. You can make them work, but you will have the problem of having it delete more than you wanted

Comment: So do you know of a way for Windows to keep the first 6 images in 4000 specific subfolders? Yes, it's a .jpeg, but feel free to give me a solution independent of the file type. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a script that works the way I need it to

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /ad') do (
 for /f "skip=6" %%b in ('dir /b %%a /on') do (
  del %%a\%%b
 )
)
```